# Cognitive Service Recommendation API Create/Trigger Build

Tags: recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

I have uploaded both catalog and usage data in model.But when creating buil d using Create/Trigger build API.Its causing following error:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "(EXT-0108) Passed argument is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "code": "EXT-0131",
      "message": "Model newmodel does not have any usage data."
    }
  }
}

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for several days and I was able to visualize two important aspects in the use of this api.

1. Currently the preview is enabled for Dynamics CRM that are created in the United States.
2. When generating the versions, they will take the records of the selected entities that are in an end state (for example the opportunities marked as won). There must be a range of records that meet the number of products in dynamics CRM, for example if there are 30 Products, there must be Quotes, Orders and offers that combine these 30 products as these systems are trained with historical data to be able to predict. If in your case you are trying to perform a spike of functionality, I recommend that you mark several of your products as unpublished and try to make as many offers, orders and quotes depending on your case that covers the largest quantity of products.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue while uploading the files

There are certain formats for both calatlog and usage files.Catalog file format is pretty simple :- "itemid" , "item name" , "product category" .You should see the catalog format section in the below link for more details on the catalog format:-

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e1.

Do the same with the usage data.The usage file is of the format :- " User Id" , "Item Id", "Time Stamp", "Event" . Notice that the first three elements are mandatory. The event type is optional. You can check out the link for more information on this topic.

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e2

This may help you to solve the issue,its work for me.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Also refer to this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/322677 for more reasons